# Match df1 with df2 and Replace it with index value (Not Inner Join)

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to match a value from df1 and replace it with the index of df2 in df1.

For example

**Input df1**

```
Column1
Test1
Test2
Test1, Test2
```

**Input df2**

```
Index ColumnA
0     Test1
1     Test2
```

So, the final output I am expecting is

**Output df1**

```
Column1
0
1
0, 1
```

I don't prefer to iterate each row value in df1 and replace due to the performance issue, but is there a function that can do this ?

Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a `replace` problem; you can pass a dictionary.

```
df1['Column1'].replace(
    dict(zip(df2['ColumnA'], df2['Index'].astype(str))), regex=True)

0       0
1       1
2    0, 1
Name: Column1, dtype: object
```

---

If you need to account for substrings (IOW, prevent matching substrings of larger strings), you can add word-boundaries for each pattern.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test1, Test2', 'Test12']})
df1

        Column1
0         Test1
1         Test2
2  Test1, Test2
3        Test12

m = {rf'\b{x}\b': str(y) for x, y in zip(df2['ColumnA'], df2['Index'])}
df1['Column1'].replace(m, regex=True)

0         0
1         1
2      0, 1
3    Test12
Name: Column1, dtype: object
```

Comment: this answer fails, when you have values like Test12. It ends up replacing 'Test1' of 'Test12' to 0 and leaves the 2. So, that becomes 02.

Comment: @Sid29 Okay, was that a requirement? It is possible to fix.

Comment: Yes, that was a requirement - It has to do a string match completely.

Comment: No, it still fails. It gives me the same output as before.

Comment: @Sid29 I don't think you tried properly (or perhaps you forgot to save, a common beginner's mistake). I've even added an example in my answer.

Comment: let me check again please. Give me a few minutes here.

Comment: Okay. Found it now - My case has both Test1 2 and Test12. It has been failing for Test1 2 and now working for Test12. I think, I will be able to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Try something different with `get_dummies`

```
x=df1.Column1.str.get_dummies(',').rename(columns=dict(zip(df2.ColumnA,df2.Index)))
x.dot(x.columns.astype(str)+',').str[:-1]
Out[23]: 
0      0
1      1
2    0,1
dtype: object
```